# Insert error sql-developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to insert data into a table:

```
INSERT INTO CIVILSTATUS
  (CivilStatusID, CivilStatusDesc)
VALUES (1, 'Single'),
       (2, 'Married'),
       (3, 'Separate'),
       (4, 'Widower');
```

But i'm getting this error:

```
Error SQL: ORA-00933: comand SQL not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

I'm doing it right or there is mistakes in my syntaxis?

Comment: To do multiple insert use insert into select or seperate into multiple insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite this as below

```
INSERT ALL 
INTO CIVILSTATUS (CivilStatusID, CivilStatusDesc) VALUES (1, 'Single')
INTO CIVILSTATUS (CivilStatusID, CivilStatusDesc) VALUES (2, 'Married')
INTO CIVILSTATUS (CivilStatusID, CivilStatusDesc) VALUES (3, 'Separate')
INTO CIVILSTATUS (CivilStatusID, CivilStatusDesc) VALUES (4, 'Widower')
SELECT * FROM CIVILSTATUS
```

Comment: This won't run, you need some sort of select statement afterwards.  It's why I don't like this method.  (Like in mayabelle's post)

Comment: Thanks, been working in mySQL for a few weeks so rusty on Oracle!

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax:

```
INSERT ALL
   INTO CIVILSTATUS (CivilStatusID, CivilStatusDesc) VALUES (1, 'Single')
   INTO CIVILSTATUS (CivilStatusID, CivilStatusDesc) VALUES (2, 'Married')
   INTO CIVILSTATUS (CivilStatusID, CivilStatusDesc) VALUES (3, 'Separate')
   INTO CIVILSTATUS (CivilStatusID, CivilStatusDesc) VALUES (4, 'Widower')
   .
   .
   .
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple rows, you need to use a select, like so:

```
insert into civilstatus
(CivilStatusID, CivilStatusDesc)
select 2, 'Married' from dual
union all select 3, 'Separate' from dual;
```